# How to get max and min dates from array using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

i want to get the min and max date form a json array:

my code

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var dates = Object.keys( data['data']['horodate'] ).map(function ( key ) {
        return data['data']['horodate'][key].replace(/\-/g,'/' ) 
    });
    var min = new Date(Math.min.apply( null, dates ));
    var max =  new Date(Math.max.apply( null, dates));
});
```

`data` array is:

```
Array [ 
    "2016/10/13 00:00:00", 
    "2016/10/13 00:30:00", 
    "2016/10/13 01:00:00", 
    "2016/10/13 01:30:00", 
    "2016/10/13 02:00:00", 
    "2016/10/13 02:30:00", 
    "2016/10/13 03:00:00", 
    "2016/10/13 03:30:00", 
    "2016/10/13 04:00:00", 
    "2016/10/13 04:30:00"
]
```

but i have an error : `Invalid date`. can you help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** with custom sort function and get the last(max) and first(min) values.

```js
data = ["2016/10/13 00:00:00", "2016/10/13 00:30:00", "2016/10/13 01:00:00", "2016/10/13 01:30:00", "2016/10/13 02:00:00", "2016/10/13 02:30:00", "2016/10/13 03:00:00", "2016/10/13 03:30:00", "2016/10/13 04:00:00", "2016/10/13 04:30:00"];

var sorted = data.slice() // copy the array for keeping original array with order
  // sort by parsing them to date
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
  });

// get the first and last values
console.log(
  'max :', sorted.pop(), 'min :', sorted.shift()
);
```

---

Or with a simple **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** loop.

```js
data = ["2016/10/13 00:00:00", "2016/10/13 00:30:00", "2016/10/13 01:00:00", "2016/10/13 01:30:00", "2016/10/13 02:00:00", "2016/10/13 02:30:00", "2016/10/13 03:00:00", "2016/10/13 03:30:00", "2016/10/13 04:00:00", "2016/10/13 04:30:00"];

// initially set max and min as first element
var max = data[0],
  min = data[0];

// iterate over array values and update min & max
data.forEach(function(v) {
  max = new Date(v) > new Date(max)? v: max;
  min = new Date(v) < new Date(min)? v: min;
});

console.log('max :', max, 'min :', min);
```

Comment: @user2203384 : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should use **[new Date(value)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)**

Nothing seems wrong in your code.

The reason of getting `Invalid date` is you're not converting date into Date object, you need to convert it in JavaScript date by `new Date()`.

**The Date object** lets you work with dates (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds)

```
var datesNew=["2016/10/13 00:00:00", "2016/10/13 00:30:00", "2016/10/13 01:00:00", "2016/10/13 01:30:00", "2016/10/13 02:00:00", "2016/10/13 02:30:00", "2016/10/13 03:00:00", "2016/10/13 03:30:00", "2016/10/13 04:00:00", "2016/10/13 04:30:00"];
//This will convert your date into Date object
$.each(datesNew, function(key, value){
    dates.push(new Date(value));
});
var min = dates.reduce(function (a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }); 
var max = dates.reduce(function (a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; });
```

```js
var datesNew=["2016/10/13 00:00:00", "2016/10/13 00:30:00", "2016/10/13 01:00:00", "2016/10/13 01:30:00", "2016/10/13 02:00:00", "2016/10/13 02:30:00", "2016/10/13 03:00:00", "2016/10/13 03:30:00", "2016/10/13 04:00:00", "2016/10/13 04:30:00"];
var dates=[];
$.each(datesNew, function(key, value){
    //Conver date in Date object
    dates.push(new Date(value));
});

var min = new Date(Math.min.apply( null, dates));
var max =  new Date(Math.max.apply( null, dates));
//var min = dates.reduce(function (a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }); 
//var max = dates.reduce(function (a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; }); 
console.log(new Date(min).toString());
console.log(new Date(max).toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```